# SSE (server sent events) disconnections

Tags: javascript, http, bottle, server-sent-events

I'm trying to use SSE (in chrome) for a ticker application.
It seems that in every sample I found or wrote the connection is closed every 3-4 seconds.
Even when running the example at :
http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_sse

you can see that an update arrives every 3-4 seconds. This is not due to the server 
implementation ("demo_sse.php" in this example), but due to a reconnect which occurs every 3-4 seconds.

If I add the following to the above example:

```
source.onerror=function(event)
{
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=source.readyState+ "<br />";
};
```

you can clearly see that the readyState is 0, meaning : "The connection has not yet been established, or it was closed and the user agent is reconnecting." (taken from the official EventSorce API doc).

I wrote a script for the server side by myself as well,
Here is the code (using python bottle web framework).

```
@route('/events')
def positions():  
    response.content_type = 'text/event-stream'
    response.set_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
    now = datetime.datetime.now().time().replace(microsecond=0)
    return  "data: %s\n\n"%now
```

And i get the same thing. Reconnecting every 3-4 seconds.

So what I'm interested is in how the connection is kept through the session.

Thanks for your help,
Omer.

Comment: Do you know the server implementation? SSE works by reconnecting when connection is lost, and how do you know this is not by purpose here?

Comment: Hi,thanks for you response. I've written a sample by myself in which I do not disconnect. All I do is return some data. Here is the code (using python bottle web framework).



@route('/events')
def positions():  
    response.content_type = 'text/event-stream'
    response.set_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
    now = datetime.datetime.now().time().replace(microsecond=0)
    return  "data: %s\n\n"%now

And i get the same thing. Reconnecting every 3-4 seconds.

Comment: Uh, please post that code [into your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11502990/edit), not as a comment - and sorry, I don't know about python or that framework. You might rephrase your question to "Why does my script [code] disconnect?"

Comment: the code is in the question. Do I need to take care of the https session not disconnected when using SSE? or does this mechanism a part of the SSE mechanism ?

Comment: I stumbled with this after almost 4 years later. To make SSE work with bottle.py you need to install the gevent module (pip instal gevent)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure bottle is not setting the Content-Length header for you. [This line](https://github.com/defnull/bottle/blob/cecbd04fc80e44f0b422b5bb7a894563102bed7f/bottle.py#L821) looks suspicious to me.

Returning an iterator, as suggested in [this issue for bottle](https://github.com/defnull/bottle/issues/42#issuecomment-969013), will probably do what you want.

```
@route('/events')
def positions():
  yield 'START'
  while stream_alive:
      some_event.wait()
      yield some_data()
  yield 'END'
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, SSE is defined to work through those reconnections.
You may trick them content-length hackery...
Like establishing content-length 0 in your headers.

Comment: In the SSE server-side connection, each data line may have a prepended 'id' definition specific for reconnections. Upon reconnection, the browser will send a "Last-Event-ID" request header with the last "id" it received in the stream and you can access that in the server script and deal with it however appropriate. Nothing to do with Content-Length.